# Can't Manual-Sync email after selectively disabling Auto-Sync - Android 5.1

Tags: sync, gmail, 5.1-lollipop

So I have two Google Accounts linked to my phone. The first is my private account which I would like to auto-sync (IE push notifications as soon as an email is received). The second is my work's account. I would like this one to auto-sync the Calendar, but not auto-sync the email, as I get 300-500 emails a day and its draining on battery life. I DO however want to be able to manual-sync the email if I need to.

Disabling Email Sync with the checkbox in either the Gmail App or Settings -> General -> Accounts&Sync -> Google -> account@example.com prevents me from manually syncing the account at all. I receive a grey banner that says "Account Sync is Off, Enable Account Sync in Account Settings" and no email with that account syncs anymore.

Am I missing something or are my options really just "Auto/None" or "Only Manual"